# video thumbnail returns black image randomly

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working in WPF and creating a gallery folder where I want to show the video thumbnails of the videos in a folder present in the system. I wrote the following code in C# to get the video thumbnails.

```
 private BitmapSource RenderThumb(Uri uri)
        {
            var player = new MediaPlayer { Volume = 0, ScrubbingEnabled = true };
            player.Open(uri);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            player.Pause();
            player.Position = player.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan
                                  ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds / 2)
                                  : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            int width = player.NaturalVideoWidth;
            int height = player.NaturalVideoHeight;

            if (width == 0 || height == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Width or Height cannot be 0");
            }

            var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            var dv = new DrawingVisual();

            using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
            {
                dc.DrawVideo(player, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
            }
            player.Close();
            rtb.Render(dv);


            Freezable frame = BitmapFrame.Create(rtb).GetCurrentValueAsFrozen();
            Freezable smallerFrame =
                BitmapFrame.Create(new TransformedBitmap(source: frame as BitmapSource, newTransform: new ScaleTransform(0.5, 0.5))).
                    GetCurrentValueAsFrozen();



            return smallerFrame as BitmapSource;
        }
```

however if I try to load thumbnails of 10 videos for example, then I get blank/black thumbnails for 2 3 videos everytime and all the others load fine. This behavior is random and sometimes I get blank thumbnails for last 3 videos and sometimes for the first 3 videos so I am not sure where to look for a solution to my issue. I have tried looking at the properties of `BitmapSource` but the properties of all 10 videos have the same info in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving `player.Close();` at the bottom of the function after rendering solved the problem for me.